# GI not allowing to filter for few columns

Tags: acumatica

I have few columns in GI which does not have any option for filter. Those columns are from customization calculated unbound decimal columns. However not all unbound columns but few still has filter option.

Any idea?

Here is the column which has filter option-

```html
#region UsrTotalCost
protected decimal? _usrTotalCost;

[PXDecimal(4)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Cost")]

public virtual decimal? UsrTotalCost
{
 get
 {
  decimal? val1 = this.BodyCost == null ? 0 : this.BodyCost;
  decimal? val2 = this.TruckCost == null ? 0 : this.TruckCost;
  decimal? val3 = this.CostOfParts == null ? 0 : this.CostOfParts;
  decimal? val4 = this.CostOfLabour == null ? 0 : this.CostOfLabour;
  decimal? val5 = this.CostOfSub == null ? 0 : this.CostOfSub;

  return val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5;
 }
}
public abstract class usrTotalCost : IBqlField { }
#endregion
```

And, here is column which does not has filter option-

```html
#region UsrProfitLost
protected decimal? _usrProfitLost;

[PXDecimal(4)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Gross Profit")]

public virtual decimal? UsrProfitLost
{
 get
 {
  decimal? val = this.GrossSale == null ? 0 : this.GrossSale;

  decimal? val1 = this.BodyCost == null ? 0 : this.BodyCost;
  decimal? val2 = this.TruckCost == null ? 0 : this.TruckCost;
  decimal? val3 = this.CostOfParts == null ? 0 : this.CostOfParts;
  decimal? val4 = this.CostOfLabour == null ? 0 : this.CostOfLabour;
  decimal? val5 = this.CostOfSub == null ? 0 : this.CostOfSub;

  return val - (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5);
 }
}
public abstract class usrProfitLost : IBqlField { }
#endregion
```

Comment: Doing a quick test on one of our unbound fields i see it is not filterable in a GI (Generic Inquiry). Not sure if this is a limitation or not. One comment I would make based on your example: you might want to add the PXDependsOnFields attribute to your unbound field that gets its value set in the getter. Without it the values might be empty in such areas as reports for example. This will not resolve your posted issue with no filter, but just an FYI. Hope you find an answer - sorry I couldn't help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm: by design, filter dialog is disabled for **all** unbound fields in GI. There is no way it can suddenly appear for some of unbound fields.

I assume there might be another DB-bound field somewhere with identical "Total Cost" caption and filter dialog...

Comment: Thank you Ruslan for clarifying that. You are right that Filter option is not available to all unbound fields. However, is there any reason, why it is disable for unbound fields?

Comment: Krunal, if filters were enabled for unbound fields in GIs, Acumatica would have to always retrieve all records from DB and filter all records in memory on application side. This would result in very noticeable performance degradation and would likely cause a lot of distraction for users. Thanks to the power of Acumatica Framework, you always have an option to create custom inquiry screen with required filter conditions, that, when designed and implemented right, would not hurt performance.

Comment: Is the same rule for custom bound fields?